# Subsetting a value based on partial pattern

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to subset out using regular expressions, the url: happy_to-learn.com.

As I'm really new to regex, could someone help with my code as to why it does not work?

```
x <- c("happy_to-learn.com", "His_is-omitted.net")
str_subset(x, "^[a-zA-Z](\\_|\\-)*\\.com$")
```

I understand that `^[a-zA-Z](\\_|\\-)*` this portion here refers to, "Start when you hit a range of alphabets from a to z or A to Z, and it contains either _ or -, if yes, then subset out this portion with 0 or more matches.

However, is it possible continue from this code by adding the back part of the value i wish to subset? i.e. `\\.com$` refers to all values that end with .com.

Is there something like `"^[a-zA-Z](\\_|\\-)*...\\.com$"` in regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to specify one or more with `+` as the `_` or `-` are not just after the first letter.

```
str_subset(x, "^[a-zA-Z]+(\\_|\\-).*\\.com$")
#[1] "happy_to-learn.com"
```

Also, the `.*` refers to zero or more characters as `.` can be any character until the `.` and 'com' at the end (`$`) of the string

Comment: could you explain what does the . after the ) mean?

Comment: What of this bit? `[a-zA-Z]` Is it similar to [a-z][A-Z]?

Comment: @NelsonGon. It implies any letter whether it is upper case or lower  case from a through z

Answer (score 1):

Why use an external package? `grep` can do it too.

```
grep("^[[:alpha:]_-]+.*\\.com$", x, value = TRUE)
#[1] "happy_to-learn.com"
```

Explanation.

1. `"^"` marks the beginning of the string.
2. `"[:alpha:]` matches any alphabetic character, upper or lower case in a portable way.
3. `"^[[:alpha:]_-]+"` between `[]`, there are alternative characters to match repeated one or more times. Alphabetic or the underscore `_` or the minus sign `-`.
4. `"^[[:alpha:]_-]+.*"` The above followed by any character repeated zero or more times.
5. `"^[[:alpha:]_-]+.*\\.com$"` ending with the string `".com"` where the dot is not a metacharacter and therefore must be escaped.